# is it possible in spark to read large s3 csv files in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Typically spark files are saved in multiple parts, allowing each worker to read different files. 
is there a similar solution when working on a single files?
s3 provides the select API that should allow this kind of behaviour.

spark appears to support this API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3select.html), but this appears to relate only for optimising queries, not for parallelising reading

Comment: Do you not mean different blocks?

Comment: split the file to parts based on lines - the s3 api supports this with the select command, but it will require also work in the spark side

Comment: each worker to read different files.   different blocks of files I would assume

Comment: And you mean HDFS files I presume?

Comment: not, the file is from s3

Comment: Not HDFS on S3, ok. That storage thing, ok unclear to me. I always had the idea that s3a, s3n etc. allowed for HDFS like access on S3. Anyway.

Comment: https://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219. Lst year we spoke to the AWS person for an EMR AWS PoC. No such mention made. I think with EMR it differs to this here. Are you using EMR or a roll your own cluster with just S3 access? Then I get it.

Comment: None the less the first sentence reads oddly.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:  this is now out of date and depends on the type of CSV.  Some CSV's allow new lines within columns.  These are un splitable.  CSVs that do not an guarantee that a newlines only represent a new row can be split

---

FYI csv's are inherently single threaded.  There is no extra information in a csv file that tells the reader where any row starts without reading the whole file from the start.

If you want multiple readers on the same file use a format like Parquet which has row groups with an explicitly defined start position defined in the footer that can be read by independent readers.  When spark goes to read the parquet file it will split out row groups into separate tasks.  Ultimately having appropriately sized files is very important for spark performance.

Comment: what about new line sign?

Answer (score 2):

S3 Select is unrelated to your use case.

1. S3 Select: have SQL select and project done in the S3 store, so that the client gets the prefiltered data. Result is returned as CSV with the header stripped, or JSON. You cannot then have >1 worker target this. (you could try, but each worker would have to read in and discard all the data in the runup to its offset, and predicting the ranges each worker can process is essentially impossible)
2. You: have > 1 worker process different parts of a file which has been *partitioned*

Partitioning large files into smaller parts for parallel processing is exactly what Spark (and mapreduce, hive etc) do for any format where it makes sense.

CSV files are easily partitioned provided they are compressed with a *splittable* compression format (none, snappy -but not gzip)

All that's needed is to tell spark what the split threshold is. For S3a, set the value fs.s3a.block.size to a value which it can then split up on, then your queries against CSV, Avro, ORC, Parquet and similar will all be split up amongst workers.

Unless your workers are doing a lot of computation per row, there's a minimum block size before it's even worth doing this. Experiment.